# What mysql extension to use on transactional database

Tags: php, mysql, transactional-database

I'm currently using the [ezsql](http://justinvincent.com/ezsql) library. Now I want to learn another method of interacting to a mysql database using php. What extension should I use if I'm connecting to a database which is used for different transactions. Should I use pdo or mysqli or some other extension that you can recommend?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not considering a framework?

Comment: @Gevious: I'm not really familiar with frameworks that connects to mysql database except for ezsql. Or are you referring to frameworks like zend or codeigniter?

Comment: Yes I was. For a medium to large project it'll be worth your while to use one...not just for DB interaction but also for a clean (mvc) architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mysqli and PDO both support transactions directly, and the old mysql_* functions can manually trigger a transaction by sending a "BEGIN TRANSACTION" query, and "COMMIT" or "ROLLBACK" queries when you're done.

I'd personally go for PDO, but that's just personal preference.  Mysqli should be fine also.